# NEO4J - Recursive query aggregation

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher

I have the following query

```
MATCH (category:Category {id:'qwe'} )
MATCH (category)-[:CHILD_OF*0..50]->(subcats:Category)<-[:PHOTO_OF]-(photo:Photo)
return (subcats.name), count(photo)
```

This query returns only the photo counts of the exact categories that photos belong to, i want aggregated count of categories photos including the photos of the child categories, i guess this used to work but broken after 2.3.x update.

Comment: [This console](http://console.neo4j.org/r/o8ywdw) uses the Cypher 2.2 compiler, and it shows that your query (without the unneeded `User` match) returns the "exact category" count -- just like Cypher 2.3. You can use the console's `Options` button on the top right to try the same query with a few different versions Cypher.

Can you provide another console demonstrating the "aggregation" behavior that you say used to work?

Comment: The result we want is to get the kittens count as 3, including the newborn kittens too @cybersam

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
MATCH (category:Category {id:'qwe'} )
MATCH (category)-[:CHILD_OF*0..50]->(subcats:Category)<-[:PHOTO_OF]-(photo:Photo)
WITH category.name AS cat, collect(subcats.name) AS subcats, count(photo) AS num
RETURN cat, subcats, num
```

Is that the behavior you are trying to achieve?

I'm not sure what might have changed between 2.2.x and 2.3 with your query. Would you be willing to share your data so we can try to reproduce?